# Does the PointerToRawData entries within section headers in a PE file hold offsets in ascending order?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, windows-10, portable-executable

> Does the `PointerToRawData` entries within section headers in a PE file hold offsets in ascending order?

Can I assume that `PointerToRawData` entries of section headers in a PE file hold offsets in ascending order, with respect to their ordering in the section table?

I see that the documentation says:

> In an image file, the VAs for sections must be assigned by the linker
>   so that they are in ascending order and adjacent, and they must be a
>   multiple of the `SectionAlignment` value in the optional header.

However, I can't find any information regarding the `PointerToRawData` member?

Please, if possible, provide source of information.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the section data, what the PointerToRawData value points to, needs to be in same order as the section headers, which need to be in VA order as you noted.

According to the Microsoft Portable Executable and Common Object File Format Specification - Revision 8.3 - February 6, 2013:

> ### Section Data
>
> [...]  Section data must appear in order of the
>   RVA values for the corresponding sections (as do the individual section headers in
>   the section table).
>
> There are additional restrictions on image files if the SectionAlignment value in the
>   optional header is less than the page size of the architecture. For such files, the
>   location of section data in the file must match its location in memory when the
>   image is loaded, so that the physical offset for section data is the same as the RVA.

Answer (score 2):

In the section table, both the `VirtualAddress` and `PointerToRawData` fields of the section headers must be ascending order, i.e. the first section header holds the lowest `VirtualAddress` and `PointerToRawData`.

I guess Microsoft made this decision to speed up the loading process.

The official PE documentation says, in the section called "**Section Data**", that:

> In an image file, the section data must be aligned on a boundary as
>   specified by the `FileAlignment` field in the optional header. Section
>   data must appear in order of the RVA values for the corresponding
>   sections (as do the individual section headers in the section table).